# jQuery UI: is there dialog window with ajax?

Tags: jquery-ui

There is one interesting widget in jquery-ui: [dialog window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

But I can't find in it's description that it could be filled with ajax source.

Maybe I've missed something...

I want a new message create form to be in opened modal window.

Thanks!

Comment: For what purpose you need ajax here? any specific requirement?

Comment: Yes, I want new message window to be in opened modal window. (I mean message create window)

Comment: @VitaliPonomar : That is the basic bahavior of modal windows in jQuery. But why are you talking about the AJAX ? Do you want to show the dialog box after an AJAX action ? Do you want to feed the dialog content with remote data?

Comment: Yes, I want feed message create form with remote data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what do you want to do.
Keep in mind that "dialog" is a UI component.

For the ajax part, you can of course fill its content like this :

```
var dialogOptions = {
        title: "A dilaog with ajax content",
        modal: true,
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        open: function() {
          $(this).load("http://a/path/to/remote/data");}
        };

$("#dialog-message").dialog(dialogOptions );
```

Then you can call the "dialog" to open like this :

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
```

Comment: I'm ok with @Pramodtech : You should give us the scenario you want to reproduce.

Comment: I want a new message create form to be in opened modal window

Comment: In the open option, you can write `$(this)` instead of `$(#...)` to make it a bit more general.